# App phonegap stopped when running

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've got an issue with a Phonegap app.

I have developed a phonegap app in Android to send and receive mail. I created a background service using a background service plugin 2.7 to update new mail. When I test on ADV then it is successful, very good. But when I export and run the app on an Android tablet, then it fails. All data loads correctly, but when the background service starts, my app stops. I don't know why.

Did anyone have a same issue? Can you help me?

Comment: Please post code where it stops working or the logcat where it stops working.

Comment: In ADV, logcat it running very good. It problem when i export-->apk file and working in device.

Comment: In my device(tablet android 4.0), my app has stopped when service start. My service be suspend.

Comment: There should still be some logcat output.  Put a filter on logcat for you application and following in DDMS. When you see something happen copy it and paste it.  There has to be a reason it is closing and it should be in there.

Comment: Thank you. I have been new idea for my app. i have several problem and i will fix it. If have issue, i will post for you.